# RabbitMQ one-consumer/one-publisher pattern

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I'm a bit confused/stuck. I've been reading around for RabbitMQ best practices, and a lot of articles come up stating that you should have two connections -- one separated for your subscriber and one for your publisher.

So what I've ended up doing is essentially started my server as so:

```
    amqp.connect(RABBIT_URL, (err, conn) => {
        conn.createChannel((ampqErr, subscribingChannel) => {
            // .....
    })

    amqp.connect(RABBIT_URL, (err, conn) => {
        conn.createChannel((ampqErr, publishingChannel) => {
            // .......
    });
```

...but I'm 99% certain this isn't the correct way to do this. So this is where my first question is. How do I maintain this rule within one service?

Also, it doesn't really work out since after a task that is done (i.e. finished scraping a page), at the end of that event, I need to fire an event that'll trigger a parsing in another service. I was pretty much doing a

```
    ch.publish(...)
```

right before I'd do the `ack`. This isn't pure as the channel I had solely for consuming is now publishing events to trigger a parse from the other service.

This type of 'event/action' order carries on through 2 other services 
(1. web/app --> 2. scrape --> 3. parse --> 4. analytics )

My plan is just to trigger an event after the completion at each service. Is this the correct way to do this?

I guess there are two questions.

Thank you.. thank you.. thank you so much to whoever can help me here. Lost an entire weekend just dabbling around. :(

Answer (score 0):

> I've been reading around for RabbitMQ best practices, and a lot of articles come up stating that you should have two connections -- one separated for your subscriber and one for your publisher.

Multiple connections and channels as a best practice do not necessarily translate well to Node, as the event loop is single threaded, you don't gain any real benefit by opening multiple channels, unless you are using child processes or some other form of threading which allows you to utilize both channels at once.

> Also, it doesn't really work out since after a task that is done (i.e. finished scraping a page), at the end of that event, I need to fire an event that'll trigger a parsing in another service. I was pretty much doing a ch.publish(...)
>   right before I'd do the ack. This isn't pure as the channel I had solely for consuming is now publishing events to trigger a parse from the other service.

This is not really an issue if you're using a single channel, which as I mentioned before, is not really a problem in Node.

> My plan is just to trigger an event after the completion at each service. Is this the correct way to do this?

I see no problem with this method, and have used it quite extensively in my own Node microservices. Rabbit is a very robust and flexible system, and everyones architecture will differ depending on their own application/service needs.